# In The Cursed Child, why didn't Harry's blood in Voldemort's body keep Harry alive?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

In *The Cursed Child*, why didn't Harry's blood in Voldemort's body keep Harry alive in the alternate timeline in which Cedric kills Neville, which meant that Nagini stays alive, and Voldemort wins the war?

This is written in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 35 (King’s Cross):

> “He took your blood believing it would strengthen him. He took into his body a tiny part of the enchantment your mother laid upon you when she died for you. His body keeps her sacrifice alive, and while that enchantment survives, so do you and so does Voldemort’s one last hope for himself.”

J.K. Rowling stated this on the F.A.Q. on her old website - the blood in the Dark Lord acted like a Horcrux for Harry and the blood in him kept the sacrifice (and therefore Harry) alive while he was:

> Having taken Harry’s blood into himself, Voldemort is keeping alive Lily’s protective power over Harry. So Voldemort himself acts almost like a Horcrux for Harry – except that the power of Lily’s sacrifice is a positive force that not only continues to tether Harry to life, but gives Voldemort himself one last chance (Dumbledore refers to this last hope in chapter 35). Voldemort has unwittingly put a few drops of goodness back inside himself; if he had repented, he could have been healed more deeply than anyone would have supposed. But, of course, he refused to feel remorse.

This meant that Harry was immortal while Voldemort was alive.

I haven't seen an answer from J.K. Rowling regarding this question yet?

Comment: I'm kind of tempted to say that JK Rowling just started to play a bit fast and loose with the plot. Cursed Child and Fantastic Beasts etc introduced a decent number of plot holes, and this might just be another one

Comment: Apart from the fact this is Cursed Child we're talking about, I got the idea that the pseudo-Horcruxes like Harry and Harry's blood in Voldemort only offer a choice to remain, rather than necessarily tether the souls to this world. Otherwise, Harry would not have been offered a choice to go either way at King's Cross.

Comment: *"Almost like"* is not the same thing as just *"like"*.

Comment: Maybe he got tired of going to King's Cross every time and just decided to die.

Comment: @Righter or maybe Harry couldn't go to King's Cross (or wherever that weird place is) twice?